# html.textboxfor() should be exactly 7 characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I need a text box which should be exactly of 7 characters,
for which I have written

```
Html.TextboxFor(x=>x.Number, new {maxLength = "7"};
```

This case takes me only 7 characters , but if I want to take less than 7, it is taking?
Is there any property like `maxlength` which takes 7 charecters only.

regards,
michael velayadu

Comment: kill me if I understand this.

Comment: listen to jlnorsworthy. you can use DataAnnotation.

Comment: add `[Range(7,7)]` to the property on the model.

Comment: @RPM1984 The RangeAttribute validates the allowed range of integers, not the allowed number of characters.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Html attribute on a textbox for Minimum Length. You can use data annotations to enforce a maximum and minimum text length for that field...

This is a pretty good walkthrough on using data annotations: [Stephen Walther on ASP.Net](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/09/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-43-use-data-annotation-validators.aspx)

Comment: Dataannotations work for postback, moreover the annotation StringLength(7) enables for less than 7 also .i want to know if there is any attribute for minlength also, but as "jlnorswothy" said there isn't , i should go for custon control.

Answer (score 2):

For what its worth, none of these answers are very clear.  What you are trying to do is set a minimum and maximum length attribute essentially.  There are basically a few ways you can accomplish this using data annotations.

The easiest way:

```
[MinLength(7)]
[MaxLength(7)]
```

Using StringLengthAttribute... StringLength has two overloaded methods.  Both have the int parameter `@maximumLength` and one of the overloads includes NamedParameters.  So for maxlength you wouldn't use a named parameter but for minlength you would:

```
[StringLength(7, MinimumLength=7)]
```

If you want to be really confusing you could also do it this way:

```
[MinLength(7)]
[StringLength(7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

With DataAnnotations using regular expressions you can enforce a string of exactly 7 charachters. DataAnnotations can also be used client-side, you just have to enable it.

Check this post for more info: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a custom validator for this. You can use the StringLength attribute to achieve what you want out of the box:

```
[StringLength(MinimumLength=7, MaximumLength=7)]
public int Number { get; set; }
```